# Google API limit errors thrown when not even close to limits

Tags: google-api, google-sheets-api

I'm using Google Sheet API in 4 different apps.

In 2 of them I'm getting this error far before I actually reach the limit:

```
GSheet error: rateLimitExceeded: Quota exceeded for quota group 'ReadGroup' and limit 'Read requests per user per 100 seconds' of service 'sheets.googleapis.com' for consumer 'project_number:xxx'.
```

I also get the same error but for writing.

You can see here, my limits are 500 requests per 100 seconds, and I max out around 15, yet I still get this error a LOT.

[image]

Any ideas?

Comment: Although I'm not sure about your actual situation, for example, when the request to Sheets API is continuously run in the loop, there is the case that an error occurs. How about this?

Comment: Have you considered reporting this in Issue Tracker? Also, could you please provide information to reproduce this? What calls are you making? Could you share the corresponding code?